# how to run this virtual device - Nexus 6 API 23

Tags: device, virtual

Intel HAXM is required to run this AVD.
Your CPU does not support VT-x.
For Nexus 6 API 23; No USB Devices or running emulators detected; Your CPU doesnt support VT-x.

Answer (score 0):

Open SDK Manager and download Intel Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer)

Ensure virtualization technology-is enabled in the BIOS settings.

EDIT: You can create an emulator but unfortunately cant use it. Since your hardware doesn't support virtualization. Get another emulator which will now act as your Deployment target. You can begin with http://www.bluestacks.com/download.html

Comment: I was able to find Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer) and installed it  but in BIOS settings couldnt find any trace of Virtualization technology. Please help. Thnx.

Comment: when i tried to troubleshoot - Your CPU doesnt support VT-x - I had this response - Unfortunately your computer doesnt support hardware accelerated virtualization - This is 10x slower than hardware accelerated virtualization!

Comment: Sorry for that but your machine doesn't support Virtualization and there's nothing you can do about that.  Try installing an emulator like 'bluestacks' works just fine. Or simply enable usb debugging on your Android device and use the actual device for testing.

Comment: Cant I create a virtual device not requiring VT-x from Select Deployment Target - Available virtual devices